# C++ interface without using a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, interface, c++14, c++17

I have the following quesiton regarding expression of interface class in c++;

so far what i have learned is that if we want want to create the interface in c+ we use a pure virtual function i.e. something like

```
class A_Interface {
      // pure virtual function
      virtual std::string helloWorld() = 0;
};
```

this question has been answered multiple times here in SO.

however if we have a complex levels of multiple inheritance something like

```
A : A_Interface
B : A

C : B

D : C
```

etc.

sometimes we do not want to override the exact same pure virtual method in all of the sub classes since it could be the case that the base class implementation is sufficient.
Moreover this is simply hard and very very time consuming, especially if we we a dealing of hundreds of classes.

Currently the only way  I know to avoid that is to use a normal virtual function. That saves me from implementing the "helloWorld" function in all of the derived classes, 
but also has the negative effect that in this case i am required to specify a default behavior otherwise error like "undefined reference to " is to be expected.

```
class A_Interface {
      // pure virtual function
      virtual std::string helloWorld(){
            return "hello from A_interface class";
        };
};
```

I am not sure if this solution is ok at all thus the following 2 questions:

1 ) Is using a simple virtual instead of pure virtual function for declaring an interface considered a bad practice? If so can you please elaborate on this why?

2) Is there a way to declare a virtual function without supplying the default implementation in the Base class in this case in the interface class A , but instead supplying at least one (or multiple implementations ) in derived classes i.e. in B, C and D.

I suppose the answer to my second question is unfortunately NO, but just want to make sure before continuing with my code. The reason why i am asking this because i am overriding a the default behavior is classes "A" and "B"  and in this case the body of "helloWorld" in class "A_Interface" is never used anyway.

the question is related if the code is compiled with the following use of -pedantic switch i.e.

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE true)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_definitions(-std=c++17 )


if(UNIX)
    add_definitions(" -pedantic -pedantic-errors -W ")
    add_definitions(" -Wall -Werror  ")
#    add_definitions(" -g  ")
endif(UNIX)
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1 ) Is using a simple virtual instead of pure virtual function for declaring an interface considered a bad practice? If so can you please elaborate on this why?

Then you are not defining an interface, or better said you are creating more than an interface, you are creating a default behavior too. Depending on your use case that's ok.

> 2) Is there a way to declare a virtual function without supplying the default implementation in the Base class in this case in the interface class A , but instead supplying at least one (or multiple implementations ) in derived classes i.e. in B, C and D.

Ofcourse. Why wouldn't it? Pure virtual in `A`, implementation in `B`. Or I don't understand the question.

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback. regarding the second answer i mean without using a pure virtual method.

Comment: @Tito "without a pure virtual method" that seems like a random requirement. Why do you impose this restriction?

Comment: well the trueth is i am simply lazy and i do not want to implement this in all of the 60 class i have here.  that's the reason

Comment: @Tito you don't implement in all 60 classes if all implementation would be the same. That would not advisable. You implement in a base class. I am sorry, I still don't see the issue here.

Comment: if the method is pure virtual i will have to override it in all of the other inherited classes.

Comment: @Tito  that's why you don't make it pure virtual and you provide an implementation for it. I fell we are moving in circles here.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind you could define the virtual method at any point of the hierarchy, and any derived class will inherit the implementation too.

You have some options, depending what you want to achieve:

1) Split `B` in `AbstractB : A` which does not provide an implementation for `helloWorld()` and `ConcreteB : AbstractB` which provides a concrete one.
Now You can choose if inherit from the class with a default behaviour or not.

2) Split your `A` interface in `AInterface` and `HelloWorldInterface`. You can now provide any concrete implementation for `HelloWorldInterface` and inherit in the way more suitable for you.

Anyway, you did not clarify enough your use case so I can't be more specific with a solution.